# how to clear a span inside a div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to clear a value of a span inside a div without deleteing other contents only the contents of a span.

ex:
body:

```
<div id="content">
  <span>one</span>

  <input type="text" />
  <input type="text" />

  <span>two</span>
  <span>three</span>

  <select>
        <option selected="selected" value=""></option>
        <option value="Monday">Monday</option>
        <option value="Tuesday">Tuesday</option>
        <option value="Wednesday">Wednesday</option>
        <option value="Thursday">Thursday</option>
        <option value="Friday">Friday</option>
        <option value="Saturday">Saturday</option>
        <option value="Sunday">Sunday</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function restSel() {
   document.getElementById("#content span").innerHTML="";
};
</script>
```

Clear all the `spans` or the content of all the `spans`.

Comment: I don't have time to really write you a full answer, but I will say this; your current use of document.getElementById is completely wrong; it accepts a standard string with no special markup, not even spaces.  And even then, it only accepts one string.  Not two as you currently have; what you have currently is closer to jquery markup.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you were using JQuery ( which will bring you much joy ), then you could do it like this.

```
$("span").html("");
```

Comment: will click later 8mins to go!

Answer (score 6):

If you're only using pure JS, you can try this:

```
document.getElementById("content").getElementsByTagName("span")[0].innerHTML="";
```

You can replace `0` to any valid index to clear certain `span`.

Answer (score 2):

Alright, I lied I guess.  This is more simpler than I thought, thanks to @Passerby;

```
for (i = 0; i < document.getElementById('content').getElementsByTagName('span').length; i++) {
    document.getElementById('content').getElementsByTagName('span')[i].innerHTML = '';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery:
To target only the *span* that are in your div with *id = "content"* (in case you have other *spans* in your document:

`$('div#content').find('span').html('');`

Comment: You should specify that the above is jquery.

Comment: Sorry about that. I assumed that OP would realise that. Updated my answer.